# setObject:ForKey: crash?

Tags: ios, crash, sigabrt

I am getting this crash in the console:

```
2011-08-27 23:26:45.041 App[1672:3117] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil key'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3231c8c3 0x362ee1e5 0x3231c7bd 0x3231c7df 0x32289679 0x3052e865 0x3220fd55 0x3221b7a3 0x3345e4b7 0x3345e38c)
terminate called throwing an exception[Switching to process 10243 thread 0x2803]
[Switching to process 10243 thread 0x2803]
```

The only line that I think would fire at the time it crashes that relates to this crash is this line:

```
UIImage *photo = [self.selectedDictionary objectForKey:@"ProfileImage"];
```

Does anything look wrong here? What could be the problem?

Edit1:
It is crashing when I do this to call a method:
Code:

```
if(actionSheet.tag == 1) {
            [self showAchievements];
        }
```

This is the showAchievements method:
Code:

```
- (void)showAchievements {
    GKAchievementViewController *achievements = [[GKAchievementViewController alloc] init];
    if (achievements != nil)
    {
        achievements.achievementDelegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:achievements animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)achievementViewControllerDidFinish:(GKAchievementViewController *)viewController
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [viewController release];
}
```

Can this crash be because I have not properly hooked everything up in iTC? I am definitely sure it crashes in that method and I do not know why.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Edit2: I am getting down to it here, in my console, right before it crashes it has a line saying Missed Method. So I search for where this NSLog is and it is in GameCenterManager.m, a file necessary for Game Center I think. Here is the method:

```
    - (void) callDelegate: (SEL) selector withArg: (id) arg error: (NSError*) err
{
    assert([NSThread isMainThread]);
    if([delegate respondsToSelector: selector])
    {
        if(arg != NULL)
        {
            [delegate performSelector: selector withObject: arg withObject: err];
        }
        else
        {
            [delegate performSelector: selector withObject: err];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Missed Method");
    }
}
```

So from that code do you see whats wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd guess the answer is right there in the code you posted:

```
reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil key'
```

You can't insert a nil key into a dictionary. Are you doing something like [myDictionary setObject:foo forKey:bar] where 'bar' is nil?

Incidentally, you also can't insert nil values into a dictionary, but that doesn't appear to be what the error reason indicates. You *can* call `[myDictionary setValue:nil forKey:bar]` (as long as bar isn't nil) - this removes the key from the dictionary. And if you want to indicate a "nil" value, you can insert the `NSNull` object into a dictionary. But keys -- keys must **always** be non-nil.

Comment: how would I properly NSLog to check if a key is nil? Also why would a key be nil since it is not an object and how would I fix it?

Comment: Look for any place that you are setting objects into a dictionary, and log the values that you're inserting. Do you always use literals (eg @"thisIsALiteral") for keys, or do you sometimes use variables? Are you doing a complex list-to-list manipulation? It's hard for me to describe every instance. Just post a couple inserts and we'll go from there.

Comment: If you see the "Missed Method" message, then the code finished that function and is probably on to the next one. I see that GameCenterManager is a 3rd-party library, and manages a dictionary of achievements. You might have an achievement somewhere with a nil identifier.

Comment: I am really at a loss. When I show the leader board view controller for Game Center everything is fine, but when I show the achievement view controller for Game Center it crashes. Any ideas? Should I post my clickedbuttonatindex which is how I invoke these view controllers (action sheet)?

Comment: I think it's the data going into these views. Just start throwing breakpoints everywhere until you find it? I have no idea, I'm not that familiar with Game Center.

Answer (score 1):

From the log it seems like the key `profileImage` equals `nil` which means that there is no data for that key in your NSDictionary.

Comment: I just checked to see if the key is nil and it is not so what else could be the problem?

Comment: Are you REALLY sure that it is not nil? any minor spelling mistske will mess it up! Try to NSLog your objectForKey: and see what comed out, can you even save images is a dictionary? I think you can't, that could be the issue, you are maybe trying to give a UIImage a wrong or even a nil value, please check that.

Comment: Also try to NSLog your whole dictionary, then you can analize it properly.

Comment: Is there a way to check what exact line an app crashes on, it seems that it is crashing somewhere else now and I need to know exactly where!

Comment: Aren't you using xcode 4? It shows you the exact line of code where it crashed.

Comment: I am but it just crashes on this cryptic line: 0x2fe1d138  <+0008>  bcc 0x2fe1d150 <__dyld___fcntl+32>

Comment: ohh ok, i have had something similar.. Do you have any code like this `[dictionary setObject: forKey:]`? If yes then it is for sure that line and then either the key or the object is nil and you need to fix the nil value by checking your code again!

Comment: I have one instance of it in my view controller and when I comment it out and ran it, it still crashes. Uggghhhh this is so annoying! Any other ideas?

Comment: omg, this is just getting weirder by the minute. It seems to be crashing when I present a Game Center Achievement view. That line in particular isn't crashing so I am guessing that a tableview delegate method is getting called when I present a new modal view? Would that happen?

Comment: I can't tell you what it is you would need to post more code. Just try commenting line per line to see which line it is, aswell set breakpoint to see whether it crashed before your breakpoint or after, then you will find the bad line.