# How to solve a NSInvalidArgumentException in a NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary

I have a problem in my code the app is crash with error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary
>   setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: app_ver)'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x874022 0x257acd6 0x81ca48 0x81c9b9 0x8732da 0x8c473 0x8c119 0x7d803 0x7d74c 0x875e42 0x82670 0x13eda49
>   0x13ebe84 0x13ecea7 0x13ebe3f 0x13ebfc5 0x1330f5a 0x2f1ca39 0x2fe9596
>   0x2f13120 0x2fe9117 0x2f12fbf 0x84894f 0x7abb43 0x7ab424 0x7aad84
>   0x7aac9b 0x133040f 0x82a35 0x12fc4d6 0x12fc447 0x99595ed9 0x995996de)
>   terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: share the code where you are trying to put values in your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You try to insert a nil object. Test for it first.

```
if(anObject){
    [myDictionary setValue:anObject forKey:kAnKey];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set a dictionary object without any key (nil).

Check this for more details: [setObject:ForKey: crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218927/setobjectforkey-crash)